# Roughly approximate the width of a string of text in Python?

Tags: python, fonts

How would one, using Python, approximate the font width of a given string of text?

I am looking for a function with a prototype similar to:

```
def getApproximateFontWidth(the_string, font_name="Arial", font_size=12):
   return ... picas or pixels or something similar ...
```

I'm not looking for anything very rigorous, an approximation will be fine.

The motivation for this is that I am generating a truncated string in my webapp's backend and sending it to the front-end to be displayed. Most of the time the strings are lower case, but sometimes the strings are in all caps, making them very wide. If the string isn't properly trucated it looks ugly. I'd like to know how much to truncate the strings based on their approximate width. If it's off by 10% it's not a big deal, this is a cosmetic feature.

Comment: Could you do it on the frontend with [CSS](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/) or [JS](http://plugins.jquery.com/ellipsis/)?

Comment: In theory yes, this could be done on the frontend, but the amount of displayed text is very small compared to the full text. I'm rendering just a snippet(one or two lines), out of what could be many pages (possibly hundreds). I'd prefer to keep it on the backend if possible.

Comment: text-overflow: ellipsis looks ugly for short texts.
hindi, tibetian, thai, korean and chinese are fixed-width, 
latin and cyrillic should be rendered by characters into a lookup-table that is quick, and then you can use that lookup table to calculate the width of any string. The arabic and urdu should be more complex because of the automatic ligatures.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Below is my simple solution, which gets you on the order of 80% accuracy, perfect for my purposes. It only works for Arial, only ascii, and it assumes 12 pt font, but it's probably proportional to other fonts as well.

```
def getApproximateArialStringWidth(st):
    size = 0 # in milinches
    for s in st:
        if s in 'lij|\' ': size += 37
        elif s in '![]fI.,:;/\\t': size += 50
        elif s in '`-(){}r"': size += 60
        elif s in '*^zcsJkvxy': size += 85
        elif s in 'aebdhnopqug#$L+<>=?_~FZT' + string.digits: size += 95
        elif s in 'BSPEAKVXY&UwNRCHD': size += 112
        elif s in 'QGOMm%W@': size += 135
        else: size += 50
    return size * 6 / 1000.0 # Convert to picas
```

And if you want to truncate a string, here it is:

```
def truncateToApproximateArialWidth(st, width):
    size = 0 # 1000 = 1 inch
    width = width * 1000 / 6 # Convert from picas to miliinches
    for i, s in enumerate(st):
        if s in 'lij|\' ': size += 37
        elif s in '![]fI.,:;/\\t': size += 50
        elif s in '`-(){}r"': size += 60
        elif s in '*^zcsJkvxy': size += 85
        elif s in 'aebdhnopqug#$L+<>=?_~FZT' + string.digits: size += 95
        elif s in 'BSPEAKVXY&UwNRCHD': size += 112
        elif s in 'QGOMm%W@': size += 135
        else: size += 50
        if size >= width:
            return st[:i+1]
    return st
```

Then the following:

```
>> width = 15
>> print truncateToApproxArialWidth("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", width) 
the quick brown fox jumps over the
>> print truncateToApproxArialWidth("THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG", width) 
THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS
```

When rendered, those strings are roughly the same width:

the quick brown fox jumps over the

THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS

Comment: Why does this seem better to you than PIL's `font.getsize('spam')`?

Comment: PIL is a sorta big library which also needs to load font files. I'm only looking for an approximation and didn't want to rely on PIL if I didn't have to.  PIL will certainly be more accurate and will probably work better for non-ascii characters, but for my purposes, the approximation is fine.

Comment: It would have been useful to list these criteria in your question.

Comment: Any link for this standard definition?

Answer (score 4):

You could render an image with the text using PIL and then determine the resulting image width.

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagefont.htm

Comment: Ya, that would be the accurate and rigorous way, but I'd like to avoid rendering images. I'm just going to write this up on my own and post here.

Comment: Use the `getsize` method of the loaded font, e.g. `font.getsize('spam')`. It returns a tuple of `(width, height)` in pixels.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a library that does this however it requires pygame:
http://inside.catlin.edu/site/compsci/ics/python/graphics.py
Look under sizeString

Comment: That looks like it's going to render the text, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

While adding a new 3rd party  dependency like PIL for just for checking string length if probably not a good idea, it is possible to use a 3rd party library just for the purpose of generating an approximation function which can be reused. This way the solution is fast, dependency free and accurate.

If the font in question is a TrueType font, you may use [PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont.getbbox](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.FreeTypeFont.getbbox). **TIP**: it is better to calculate the widths with a overly sized font first as getbbox returns integers.

#### Example with custom font: Inter-Regular

##### Part 1: Generating the widths

```py
import string

from PIL import ImageFont

WIDTH_DICT = dict()

supported_chars = [c for c in string.printable if not c.isspace() or c == ' ']


font_file_path = str(Path("~/.fonts/Inter-Regular.ttf").expanduser())
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_file_path, 15)

for char in supported_chars:
    left, _, right, _ = font.getbbox(char)
    width = right - left
    WIDTH_DICT[char] = width
    

AVERAGE_WIDTH = sum(WIDTH_DICT.values()) / len(WIDTH_DICT)

print(f'{WIDTH_DICT=}')
print(f'{AVERAGE_WIDTH=}')
```

which outputs

```
WIDTH_DICT={'0': 9, '1': 7, '2': 9, '3': 10, '4': 10, '5': 9, '6': 9, '7': 9, '8': 9, '9': 9, 'a': 8, 'b': 9, 'c': 8, 'd': 9, 'e': 9, 'f': 6, 'g': 9, 'h': 9, 'i': 4, 'j': 5, 'k': 8, 'l': 4, 'm': 13, 'n': 9, 'o': 9, 'p': 9, 'q': 9, 'r': 6, 's': 8, 't': 5, 'u': 9, 'v': 8, 'w': 12, 'x': 8, 'y': 8, 'z': 8, 'A': 10, 'B': 10, 'C': 11, 'D': 11, 'E': 9, 'F': 9, 'G': 11, 'H': 11, 'I': 4, 'J': 8, 'K': 10, 'L': 8, 'M': 13, 'N': 11, 'O': 11, 'P': 10, 'Q': 11, 'R': 10, 'S': 10, 'T': 10, 'U': 11, 'V': 10, 'W': 14, 'X': 10, 'Y': 10, 'Z': 9, '!': 4, '"': 6, '#': 10, '$': 10, '%': 12, '&': 10, "'": 3, '(': 5, ')': 5, '*': 8, '+': 10, ',': 4, '-': 7, '.': 4, '/': 5, ':': 4, ';': 4, '<': 10, '=': 10, '>': 10, '?': 8, '@': 14, '[': 5, '\\': 5, ']': 5, '^': 7, '_': 8, '`': 7, '{': 5, '|': 5, '}': 5, '~': 10, ' ': 4}
AVERAGE_WIDTH=8.31578947368421
```

##### Part 2: Creating width calculator function

Now just define your function as:

```py
WIDTH_DICT={'0': 9, '1': 7, '2': 9, '3': 10, '4': 10, '5': 9, '6': 9, '7': 9, '8': 9, '9': 9, 'a': 8, 'b': 9, 'c': 8, 'd': 9, 'e': 9, 'f': 6, 'g': 9, 'h': 9, 'i': 4, 'j': 5, 'k': 8, 'l': 4, 'm': 13, 'n': 9, 'o': 9, 'p': 9, 'q': 9, 'r': 6, 's': 8, 't': 5, 'u': 9, 'v': 8, 'w': 12, 'x': 8, 'y': 8, 'z': 8, 'A': 10, 'B': 10, 'C': 11, 'D': 11, 'E': 9, 'F': 9, 'G': 11, 'H': 11, 'I': 4, 'J': 8, 'K': 10, 'L': 8, 'M': 13, 'N': 11, 'O': 11, 'P': 10, 'Q': 11, 'R': 10, 'S': 10, 'T': 10, 'U': 11, 'V': 10, 'W': 14, 'X': 10, 'Y': 10, 'Z': 9, '!': 4, '"': 6, '#': 10, '$': 10, '%': 12, '&': 10, "'": 3, '(': 5, ')': 5, '*': 8, '+': 10, ',': 4, '-': 7, '.': 4, '/': 5, ':': 4, ';': 4, '<': 10, '=': 10, '>': 10, '?': 8, '@': 14, '[': 5, '\\': 5, ']': 5, '^': 7, '_': 8, '`': 7, '{': 5, '|': 5, '}': 5, '~': 10, ' ': 4}
AVERAGE_WIDTH=8.31578947368421

def get_width_inter_font_15(string:str) -> float:
  return sum(WIDTH_DICT.get(s, AVERAGE_WIDTH) for s in string)
```

This can be then used as:

```py
>>> get_width_inter_font_15("the quick brown fox jumps over the")
252
>>> get_width_inter_font_15("THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS")
231
```

This ratio 252/231 is 1.091, which is pretty close what I see when comparing the widths of images created from the strings: 1.078 (given by Inkscape)

[image]

As the widths returned from getbbox are integers, using a larger font size helps. For example, with font size 500:

```
>>> get_width_inter_font_500("THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS")
7722
>>> get_width_inter_font_500("the quick brown fox jumps over the")
8358
```

Here the estimated ratio is 1.082 which is only 0.4% larger than what Inkscape says.

##### About speed

The generated function `get_width_inter_font_500` is about 1000x faster than using PIL:

```py
>>> %timeit get_width_inter_font_500("the quick brown fox jumps over the")
3.04 µs ± 10.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
>>> def pil_width(string):
      total = 0
      for char in string:
          left, _, right, _ = font.getbbox(char)
          width = right - left
          total += width
      return total
    
>>> pil_width("the quick brown fox jumps over the")
8358
>>> %timeit pil_width("the quick brown fox jumps over the")
3.6 ms ± 22.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: This is a great solution, easily extendable to other fonts as well.