# Length of a string in a specific font

Tags: string, perl, fonts

I am trying to calculate the length of a string in a a font. The goal is to create texts like:

```
DD  Qui n'a pu l'obtenir ne le méritait pas.
LC  Ne le méritait pas! Moi?    
DD                           Vous!  
LC                                 Ton impudence    
    Téméraire vieillard, aura sa récompense
```

In a fixed font (as above), this is easy. For proportional fonts, I can make an acceptable approximation of the previous line length with:

```
use Tk;
use Tk::Font;

my $mw = MainWindow->new();
my $font = $mw->fontCreate( 'TimesNew Roman' );

sub timesspace {
    (my $text)=@_;
    my $retval= $font->measure( $text );
    return int($retval);
}
```

(a reasonable estimation, because the Tk fonts are not exactly the same as the output-processor's font).

This however, requires a graphical environment (because I create a Tk window), even though al the scripts are CLI only. This leads to:

```
couldn't connect to display "localhost:11.0" at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Tk/MainWindow.pm line 53.
MainWindow->new() at /usr/local/bin/xml3roff line 10.
```

Is there a reliable and simple way of finding the length of a string in Times/Helvetica/... without the need of such an environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Roughly approximate the width of a string of text in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007743/roughly-approximate-the-width-of-a-string-of-text-in-python) as referred to by @Joshua, I created my own estimation of the font sizes.

The Adobe Font Metrics are indeed not generally available.
As a reference, I used the groff fonts that should be available on most Linux systems. There are some issues with the glyph names and the representations. My input texts contain é, ü etc. and the font file contains `'e`, `:u` etcetera. So, I use `groff` to generate a table that is parsable for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpfont=tmpfont

font=$(basename $1)
if [ ! -f "/usr/share/groff/current/font/devps/$font" ] ; then
    echo "No suchfont $font"
    exit
fi

cp "/usr/share/groff/current/font/devps/$font" $tmpfont
sed -i '1,/charset/d' $tmpfont
sed -i 's/,.*//' $tmpfont
sed -i 's/^\(..\)\t/\\(\1  /'  $tmpfont
sed -i 's/^\(...\)\t/\\[\1]  /'  $tmpfont
sed -i '/^\(.....*\)\t/d'  $tmpfont
sed -i '/"/d'  $tmpfont
sed -i 'a .br'  $tmpfont
groff $tmpfont > $tmpfont.ps

ps2ascii $tmpfont.ps  | sed 's/ //g;s/^\(.\)/\1 /'>$font.measure
```

And to determine the width of the string I use:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;


my %fontmeasure;

if (open ( my $FONT,'<',"TI.measure")){
    while (<$FONT>){
        chomp;
        (my $char,my $width)=split '    ';
        $fontmeasure{$char}=$width;
    }
    close $FONT;
}
else {
    die "Can't open font measure";
}
$fontmeasure{' '}=250;

my @str;
while (<>){
    undef @str;
    @str=split (//);
    my $total=0;
    for (@str){
        if (defined($fontmeasure{$_})){
            $total=$total+$fontmeasure{$_};
        }
        else {
            $total=$total+250;
        }
    }
    print "$total\n";
}
```

For those interested: the text given in the question will produce:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [`Font::AFM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Font::AFM) might be what you're after, but it relies on Adobe Font Metrics (AFM) files which may not be installed on your system.

Alternatively, you could try to approximate it like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007743/roughly-approximate-the-width-of-a-string-of-text-in-python).

Comment: Indeed, AFM is not an option due to its unavailability.You got me thinking though about groff's fonts.